# AngularJS ngOptions not populating dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I do not understand why ng-options is not populating the dropdown menu. JSON data is being returned from the service. I can `console.log` the data in the controller. So, why is `ng-options` not populating the dropdown

```
<tr class="info">
   <td class = "col-xs-3">Maximum page size: </td>
   <td class = "col-xs-9" ng-controller = "converseController"> Show conversations per page 
   <select ng-model = "selectedNumber" ng-options="conversation for conversation in conversations">
        <option value = ""> Choose the number of conversations </option>
   </select>

   <aside id = "pageSize"> Show contacts per page 
      <select>
         <option> 20 </option>
      </select>
   </aside>
 </td>
</tr>
```

`converse.js` - Controller

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    var converseController = function (getData, $scope) {
        var url = '../../data/conversation.json';
        getData.fetchData(url)
            .then(function(data){
                    $scope.coversations = data.conversation;
                    console.log($scope.coversations);
        });
    };

    angular.module('assignment3App')
      .controller ('converseController', ['getData', '$scope', converseController]);        
}());
```

`conversation.json`

```
{
    "conversation": [
        10,  
        20,
        30,  
        40, 
        50,  
        60, 
        70, 
        80,  
        90,
        100
    ]
}
```

Service - `promise.js`

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  var getData = function (fetchDataService) {
      this.fetchData = function(filePath) {

             return fetchDataService.getContent(filePath)
                .then(function (returnedData) {
                    return returnedData.data;
                  });
              };   
      };    

      angular.module('assignment3App')
        .service ('getData', ['fetchDataService', getData]);
}());
```

Service - `callJson.js`

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  var fetchDataService = function($http) {
      this.getContent = function(path) {
        return $http({
            method : 'get',
            url : path
          });
      };
  };

  angular.module('assignment3App')
    .service ('fetchDataService', fetchDataService);
}());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assinging the array to the wrong scope variable. `$scope.coversations = data.conversation;` should be spelt `$scope.conversations = data.conversation;`.

Comment: Thanks. I am sorry that was a stupid question. I didn't know what to do. I spent a lot of time figuring out what I was doing wrong. Never thought it could be as simple as a typo.